# Can we define $\in$ given $\subset$ and $r$, a "recursive singleton-stripping operator"?

Tags: set-theory

I'm interested in alternative non-logical languages for set theory, particularly $\mathrm{ZFC}$ because it is so well-studied.

I'm wondering whether we can recover $\in$ using $\subset$ and $r$, an operation that removes outer "singleton wrappers" from sets recursively.

First a word on notation, let an uppercase Latin letter be a free variable. Let a lowercase Latin vowel be a variable bound by a universal quantifier. Let a lowercase Latin consonant be a variable bound by a non-universal quantifier. Additionally, $u$, $v$, and $r$ are function symbols when used in function position.

Let $u$ be an operator defined in the following way. Let $v$ be another function which "wraps a set" in a singleton. $v$ should be thought of as being similar to an inverse of $u$, but is not a strict inverse.

$v$ defined to be the singleton containing its argument.

$$ v(X) = \{X\} $$

$u(X)$ is the sole element of $X$ if $X$ is a singleton and $X$ itself otherwise.

$$ u(X) = \cup X \;\; \text{if}\;\; |X|=1 $$
$$ u(X) = X \;\; \text{if}\;\; |X| \ne 1 $$

If we consider ZFC extended with $\subset$ and $u$, then the following holds.

$$ X \in Y \leftrightarrow v(X) \subset Y $$

$ v(X) \subset Y $, however, can be expressed in terms of $u$. Consider the following chain of equivalences.

$$ v(X) \subset Y $$
$$ \exists! b \mathop. v(X) = b \land b \subset Y $$
$$ \exists! b \mathop. X = u(b) \land X \ne b \land b \subset Y $$

This means that we can consider $\in$ to be an orthographic abbreviation in $\mathrm{ZFC}[\subset, u] - \{\in\}$.

However, $u$ has an interesting property in $\mathrm{ZFC}[u]$, namely that $u(X), u(u(X)), u^3(X), u^4(X) \cdots $ eventually stabilizes.

let $r(X)$ be what we eventually settle on.

$$ r_1(X) = u(X) $$
$$ r_{n+1}(X) = u(r_{n}(X)) $$

And thus $r$ can be defined in the following way.

$$ r(X) = \cup \{ r_n(X) : r_n(X) = r_{n+1}(X) \} $$

Metaphorically speaking, $r$ strips as many singleton set "wrappers" from a set as it can.

Is $\in$ definable given just $\subset$ and $r$?

So far the closest I have been able to come is the following:

This condition holds if $X \subset Y$, but the converse is clearly false.

$$ \exists z \mathop. r(X) = r(z) \land z \subset Y $$

I haven't been able to find a way to "jump up exactly one level" using $r$.

Comment: The function $u$ is not injective, and most of the times $\{X\}$ is not the only element of $u^{-1}(X)$.

Comment: I'm defining $u^{-1}$ separately from $u$ and intentionally abusing notation. I'll make that more clear.

Comment: For example use another letter, say $v$.